# Does adding DC offset to RF output signal affect the range of RF transmission?

Tags: rf, dc, radio

Does adding DC offset to AC output signal affect the range of RF transmission?

Adding DC offset does not magnify the AC signal, it is just an offset with more power for the output.

I had once asked a similar question for some time ago.

[More voltage for radio carrier frequency, is that all?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/683564/more-voltage-for-radio-carrier-frequency-is-that-all)

The answer is alright. The fact is, for more RF transmission range, I need more voltage for output RF signal going to antenna. I mean, even the signal will not change its original property, will it travel for a longer distance when I try to make a RF transmission?

[image: picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DC component will not increase the range, as only the RF will be radiated.

Depending on the antenna type either no DC current will flow (antennas that measure as an open circuit with an ohmmeter) or the DC will be short circuited (antennas with DC continuity). Some antennas have a coil that causes a DC short, connecting a DC supply to those will possibly cause smoke.

One case where DC and RF are combined is in antenna systems with a remote amplifier. A receive, transmit, or rx/tx amplifier can be located right at the antenna and powered through the same feedline that carries the RF signal. This can improve performance by reducing the effects of feedline losses. In this system the RF and DC have to be separated at each end of the feedline using something like [bias tees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_tee). For example, you might see something like this where an amplifier is used at the antenna to boost the signal before it goes through a long feedline. If the amp were at the receiver end it would be amplifying the signal with the line losses, increasing noise. This is commonly done with over-the-air television antennas.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkXUC7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The same principle can be used for transmitting, suppose you have a 100 W amplifier that takes a 1 W input. If you put it through a coax with 3 dB loss (half the power) you'll get 50 W at the antenna with 50 W lost in the coax, but if you put it at the antenna end you get the full 100 W at the antenna, and you only need to increase the drive to 2 W to make up for 1 W lost in the coax.

Answer (score 3):

> *I mean, even the signal will not change its original property, will it
> travel for a longer distance when I try to make a RF transmission?*

Absolutely not.

> *Does adding DC offset to RF output signal affect the range of RF
> transmission?*

Not unless the transmitter carrier is subsequently processed through some non-linear circuit that disproportionately allows a bigger portion of the carrier through when it has a bigger DC offset.

Comment: I mean the impedance of antenna will be the same, when I apply more voltage with proper current. This means more power for the antenna. Am I right? W=(I**2)*R There would be more current on the antenna, so it will cause more range.

Comment: @lastime no, there wouldn't be more current on the antenna hence, the range at which you can receive it remains the same. The impedance of a regular monopole or dipole antenna is infinite at DC.